# Leaf at Same level in a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

i made a code that checks if all the leaf nodes are at same level or not but my code is not passing all the test case can anyone help me to find the mistake.

```
static boolean ans;
static void solve(Node root,int h,int ma){
    if(root==null)
    return;
    
    if(ans==false)
    return;
    
    if(root.left==null&&root.right==null)
    {
        if(ma==-1)
        ma = h;
        else{ 
        if(h != ma)
        ans = false;
            
        }
        
        return;
    }
    
    solve(root.left,h+1,ma);
    solve(root.right,h+1,ma);
}
boolean check(Node root)
{
// Your code here   
ans = true;
int ma = -1,h=0;
solve(root,h,ma);
return ans;
```

Comment: 1691 6733 N 5989 6640 N 2750 3565 N 1371 5003 N 1677 8921 N 8413 7729 N 7679 2475 N 2822 6415 N 3872  This is the test case where it fails

Answer (score 0):

The variable `ma` is a *parameter*. When you assign the height of the left most leaf node to `ma` and return back (from recursion), it won't be reflected in the caller.

Make `ma` an instance variable or static just like `ans` and remove it as a parameter.